# Is there a Ruby http client library with a response cache?

Tags: ruby, http, client, request, etag

Is there a Ruby http client library where responses are automatically cached by ETag and the If-Non-Match header applied to requests on previously used URLs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to check the list of "[Ruby HTTP clients features](http://web.archive.org/web/20150105171335/https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0AiZsKd8d4hSJdHFFbjR5aWNjWjlzWlhiNGxQejdBWWc&output=html)" (archived version from January 2015) for a complete overview.

Comment: Thanks; the comparison table is what I really need!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Faraday-HTTP-Cache](https://github.com/plataformatec/faraday-http-cache).

Answer (score 0):

[rufus-jig](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-jig) supports conditional GET.